# How can I debug an Angular website started with grunt serve inside WebStorm?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, gruntjs, webstorm

I am trying to debug my AngularJS site from within WebStorm.
The site is served with "grunt serve".
I have the Jetbrains IDE support plugin installed in Chrome and it is configured to work on the default port 63342.

I use

- Windows 8.1 as development platform
- Webstorm 2016.3.1
- "grunt-contrib-connect": "~1.0.2"

In Webstorm I created a run-configuration of type JavaScript debug.
In there I have put:

- URL field to http://localhost:9001 which is the same as configured in
  the gruntfile.
- Browser: default (chrome)
- Remote URLS of local files:
  src folder mapped to http://localhost:9001

When I run grunt serve, my site starts in chrome.
When I hit the debug button for the JavaScript debug configuration, The debugger window shows but after a while a popup says "Waiting for connection from JetyBrains IDE Support extension" from Chrome. Please ensure you have installed..."

I also do not get the yellow popup in Chrome telling that the Jetbrains IDE Support extension is functional.

When I go and look in the console for _generated_background_page.html of the Jetbrains IDE Support extension, I see the following message:

```
IN [21,"Debugger","attach",["http://localhost:9001",true]]
```

But then nothing happens anymore.

Does someone have a step by step manual on how to debug an AngularJS site ran with Grunt serve from within WebStorm?

Comment: Open Chrome debogger et put breakpoint within the Scripts section of the debogger. If you want to make it work with Jetbrains aniway, it's not related to grunt or webstorm apparently, just between your ide and chrome.

Comment: Webstorm is the IDE ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: I needed to change the host setting in the options of the Jetbrains IDE Support extension. It had the value of **"127.0.0.1"** and when I **changed** it **to** **"localhost"**, things started to work out!

[image]

Comment: Are you under windows (or a windows's VM) ? I remember sometime to have some trouble like this with it, yet never had something similar under linux.

Comment: Yes, I am running on Windows.

Comment: such issues may be caused by proxy servers/firewalls blocking requests on `127.0.0.1 `...